# Append json_object_arrays in C using jsonc library

Tags: c, arrays, json, json-c

I am new to the C language. I need to append two `json_object` arrays created with the `json-c` library. This is my code:

```
struct json_object *obj1,*array1,*array2,*array3;

obj1 = json_object_new_object();    

array1 = json_object_new_array();
json_object_array_add(array1, json_object_new_int(1));
json_object_array_add(array1, json_object_new_int(2));
json_object_array_add(array1, json_object_new_int(3));  

json_object_object_add(obj1, "array1", array1);

array2 = json_object_new_array();
json_object_array_add(array2, json_object_new_int(4));
json_object_array_add(array2, json_object_new_int(5));
json_object_array_add(array2, json_object_new_int(6));  

json_object_object_add(obj1, "array2", array2);

json_object_object_add(obj1, "array3", array1+array2);
```

But I got the following error:

> error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘struct json_object *’ and ‘struct json_object *’)
>          json_object_object_add(obj1, "array3", array1+array2);

Is this not possible? I need output like this:

```
{
   "array1:[1,2,3],
   "array2":[4,5,6],
   "array3":[1,2,3,4,5,6]
}
```

Or is it possible to add a normal C integer array to Json, like this

```
int32_t smp[100]={0};

smp[0] = 1;
smp[1] = 2;
smp[2] = 3;
smp[3] = 4;
smp[4] = 5;
smp[5] = 6;

json_object_object_add(obj1, "array3", smp);
```

Comment: `array1+array2`  isn't possible in C.

Comment: then how to add json_object_arrays

Comment: I do not know the json-c library, sorry.

Comment: My guess is you have to create a new array that adds up the two you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no "built-in" function in `json-c` to concatenate two arrays, but you can easily create one:

```
struct json_object * json_object_array_concat (struct json_object *array1,
                                               struct json_object *array2) {
    struct json_object *array3 = json_object_new_array();
    if (!array3) {
        return NULL;
    }
    int i,
        size1 = json_object_array_length(array1),
        size2 = json_object_array_length(array2);
    for (i = 0; i < size1; ++i) {
        json_object_array_add(array3, json_object_array_get_idx(array1, i));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size2; ++i) {
        json_object_array_add(array3, json_object_array_get_idx(array2, i));
    }
    return array3;
}
```

Then to use it:

```
array3 = json_object_array_concat(array1, array2);
```

If you only want to append `array2` to `array1`:

```
struct json_object * json_object_array_append (struct json_object *array1,
                                               struct json_object *array2) {
    int i,
        size2 = json_object_array_length(array2);
    for (i = 0; i < size2; ++i) {
        json_object_array_add(array1, json_object_array_get_idx(array2, i));
    }
    return array1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remember that above answers do not address the reference counts in json-c.  They add the objects to the destination array, but do not have it take ownership of them. They will likely cause segfaults etc.

The doc: ["The reference count will *not* be incremented."](https://json-c.github.io/json-c/json-c-0.10/doc/html/json__object_8h.html#acc89c0f58947d499e2868ac8b62bed49)

To ensure that ownership is held by both arrays, you need something like this:

```
void json_object_array_append(json_object *dest, json_object *src) {
    int i;
    int src_size = json_object_array_length(src);
    for (i = 0; i < src_size; ++i) {
        json_object *src_item = json_object_array_get_idx(src, i);
        json_object_get(src_item); // increment reference count
        json_object_array_add(dest, src_item); // add to dest array
    }
}

// optional: if you are disposing of the src array, you can then do this:
json_object_put(src);
// after calling the append function.
```